# The difference between one and many "type" blocks in Delphi

Tags: delphi, syntax, compilation, delphi-2007

I've been programming Delphi for five or six years now and I consider myself fairly good at it, but I stumbled across a behavior recently which I couldn't really explain. I was writing a simple linked list, let's call it a TIntegerList. The example code below compiles correctly:

```
type
  PIntegerValue = ^TIntegerValue;

  TIntegerValue = record
    Value: Integer;
    Next: PIntegerValue;
    Prev: PIntegerValue;
  end;
```

However, the code below does not (saying TIntegerValue is undeclared):

```
type
  PIntegerValue = ^TIntegerValue;

type  
  TIntegerValue = record
    Value: Integer;
    Next: PIntegerValue;
    Prev: PIntegerValue;
  end;
```

How exactly is the "type" keyword handled in Delphi? What is the syntactical meaning of having several types declared under one "type" keyword, compared to having one "type" per type? Alright, that was confusing, but I hope the code example helps explain what I mean. I am working in Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logically there's no need to use the `type` keyword when the code is already part of an existing type declaration section. So,

```
type
  TRec1 = record
  end;

  TRec2 = record
  end;
```

produces types that are indistinguishable from

```
type
  TRec1 = record
  end;

type
  TRec2 = record
  end;
```

However, as you have discovered, the compiler has a limitation that requires all forward declarations to be fully resolved before the end of the section where the forward declaration was introduced.

There's no particular reason that it has to be that way. It would be perfectly possible for the compiler to relax that limitation. One can only assume that a compiler implementation detail, probably originating a very long time ago, has leaked into the language specification.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I was expecting! No real syntactical meaning, just a somewhat arbitrary limitation in the compiler :)

Comment: From the Turbo Pascal Programmer's Guide (TP6) about pointer types: "If the base type is an undeclared identifier, it must be declared in the same type declaration part as the pointer type.". In latest Delphi version, [`Pointer Types`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)#Pointer_Types) has the following note: "Note: You can declare a pointer type before you declare the type it points to."

Answer (score 2):

This pure standard Pascal. Since Pascal compilers are usually one-pass and there is no forward declaration for types, this feature was defined in the original Pascal by N. Wirth to allow such 'recursive' types for e.g. linked lists etc.

Comment: Where does one pass come into this?

Comment: I also question your history. I'm looking at Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs right now, I have it before me. And linked lists are introduced using this construct: `TMyRecord = record P: ^TMyRecord; end;`

Answer (score 0):

I have already given a comment but it is to be peer-reviewed. This is rather in effective. Therefore here is another answer. This may be merged or what ever you want.

In "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs" Wirth gives an example in "Program 4.1 Straight List Insertion"

```
type
  ref  = ^word;
  word = record
           key: integer;
           count: integer;
           next: ref
         end;
```

Comment: I'll take another look at this tomorrow when I am re-united with my copy of A+DS=P. Is there are statement in there saying what the forward declaration rules are in Wirth's original language? Also, you need not to create new user accounts. SO doesn't work well like that. I'll see if I can get them merged for you.

Comment: Can you go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge and merge your user profiles. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see that. I was looking in section 4.3.1. Of course, the algos don't need to be very complex before you need forward declaration of pointer types. For example, code block 4.28, page 184.